# The order number belongs to the user or not

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I wanted to make a series of changes on the page checkout/thankyou.php woocommerce

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
  if ( order number Belongs to user ???? )  {
   show order details
} else { echo 'not show order details'; }
}
```

But I do not know how to check whether the order number belongs to the user or not

- If the custom number entered belongs to him, show the order details
- If the order number does not belong to the user, do not display the order details

I searched the site for about 3 hours but did not find anything, then I decided to ask a question

Comment: But in woo-commerce default customers can not access other customer orders even if they have an order id unless the user has both order id and key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check with user id from order object `$order->user_id;` and check against the current logged-in user id for that you can use `get_current_user_id()`. try the below code.

**thankyou.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Thankyou page
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/checkout/thankyou.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files, and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce\Templates
 * @version 3.7.0
 */

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;


$user_id = $order->user_id;

if( is_user_logged_in() && $user_id == get_current_user_id() ){ ?>

<div class="woocommerce-order">

    <?php
    if ( $order ) :

        do_action( 'woocommerce_before_thankyou', $order->get_id() );
        ?>

        <?php if ( $order->has_status( 'failed' ) ) : ?>

            <p class="woocommerce-notice woocommerce-notice--error woocommerce-thankyou-order-failed"><?php esc_html_e( 'Unfortunately your order cannot be processed as the originating bank/merchant has declined your transaction. Please attempt your purchase again.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>

            <p class="woocommerce-notice woocommerce-notice--error woocommerce-thankyou-order-failed-actions">
                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $order->get_checkout_payment_url() ); ?>" class="button pay"><?php esc_html_e( 'Pay', 'woocommerce' ); ?></a>
                <?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) : ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ) ); ?>" class="button pay"><?php esc_html_e( 'My account', 'woocommerce' ); ?></a>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </p>

        <?php else : ?>

            <p class="woocommerce-notice woocommerce-notice--success woocommerce-thankyou-order-received"><?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_thankyou_order_received_text', esc_html__( 'Thank you. Your order has been received.', 'woocommerce' ), $order ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?></p>

            <ul class="woocommerce-order-overview woocommerce-thankyou-order-details order_details">

                <li class="woocommerce-order-overview__order order">
                    <?php esc_html_e( 'Order number:', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
                    <strong><?php echo $order->get_order_number(); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?></strong>
                </li>

                <li class="woocommerce-order-overview__date date">
                    <?php esc_html_e( 'Date:', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
                    <strong><?php echo wc_format_datetime( $order->get_date_created() ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?></strong>
                </li>

                <?php if ( is_user_logged_in() && $order->get_user_id() === get_current_user_id() && $order->get_billing_email() ) : ?>
                    <li class="woocommerce-order-overview__email email">
                        <?php esc_html_e( 'Email:', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
                        <strong><?php echo $order->get_billing_email(); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?></strong>
                    </li>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <li class="woocommerce-order-overview__total total">
                    <?php esc_html_e( 'Total:', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
                    <strong><?php echo $order->get_formatted_order_total(); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?></strong>
                </li>

                <?php if ( $order->get_payment_method_title() ) : ?>
                    <li class="woocommerce-order-overview__payment-method method">
                        <?php esc_html_e( 'Payment method:', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
                        <strong><?php echo wp_kses_post( $order->get_payment_method_title() ); ?></strong>
                    </li>
                <?php endif; ?>

            </ul>

        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou_' . $order->get_payment_method(), $order->get_id() ); ?>
        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', $order->get_id() ); ?>

    <?php else : ?>

        <p class="woocommerce-notice woocommerce-notice--success woocommerce-thankyou-order-received"><?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_thankyou_order_received_text', esc_html__( 'Thank you. Your order has been received.', 'woocommerce' ), null ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?></p>

    <?php endif; ?>

</div>

<?php }else{

    echo 'Your custom message here.';

} ?>
```